# how to create SELECT query with some conditions

Tags: c#, sql

There is a query

```
  string query=string.Format("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='{0}'
                              AND name='{1}'",textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text);
```

How to make that this query could return such results.
Example of work.

table

```
1 xx
2 yy
3 xx
```

1)

```
textbox1.Text=="";
textbox2.Text=="";
```

result -

```
1 xx
2 yy
3 xx
```

2)

```
textbox1.Text=="";
textbox2.Text=="xx";
```

result -

```
1 xx
3 xx
```

Comment: But this is **NOT** a question..... **what** is your question????

Comment: You simply cannot do that with that query. You must alter your query (using one param or not) according to user input.

Comment: Assuming that you're trying to bind the text boxes to a selected name and id, why would leaving the "id" text box blank and changing the "name" text box delete record 2 (or any record)?

Comment: So far, the asker is looking for some statements that satisfy his examples, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try with below statements, thanks

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1 "
                + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) ? "" : " AND id='" + textBox1.Text + "' ")
                + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text) ? "" : " AND name='" + textBox2.Text + "' ");
```

Comment: .... and it's a great entry way for anyone hacking your site using SQL injection ....

Comment: Just answered accordingly, however, using parametrized query is safe to use, please see example here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter , thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the question is so this is from assumption.

```
string query=@"SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1 ";

if(textBox1.Text != "")
query += " and id=" + textBox1.Text;

if(textBox2.Text != "")
query += " AND name= " + textBox2.Text;
```

Comment: Your generated query will provide error for string type data.

Comment: we have no clue what his datatypes are, and this is what i use all the time and have no problems with it.  also the your code does the same just written differently.. ;)

Comment: Thats write, but, guess the `name` field, certainly its string or varchar, thanks for your time.